# is the Sudoku puzzle NP-complete?

Tags: puzzle, np-complete

In general Sudoku on $n^2 \times n^2$ boards of $n \times n$ blocks is NP-complete.

> Is the common Sudoku on $9 \times 9$ board NP-complete?

Comment: I don't know anything about complexity theory, but isn't Sudoku on a fixed-size board trivially a polynomial-time problem, namely $O(1)$, since you just have to check each of the possible boards?

Comment: It has exponential space complexity but a constant time complexity

Comment: @AnuragPallaprolu, that is impossible: the space complexity is always bounded above by the time complexity, simply because *using the space* needs time!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I was comparing the complexities of different procedures. The exponential space complexity was that of visualizing all possible SuDoKu boards and the constant time complexity was that of mapping the given configuration to the right board, since every board has an exact answer.

Comment: @AnuragPallaprolu, I dpon't understand your comment.

Comment: looking for refs on the NP completeness of sudoko hope someone can link this question.

Comment: edge coloring problem (which is NP complete) can be reduced to a sudoku problem proving that sudoku problem is NP complete.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The 9x9 board cannot be NP-complete, because there are finitely many instances of the problem.

Comment: @MattG, no, it isn't.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Your explanation is left a bit vague. If a problem has finitely many instances, it is never NP-complete? Is there a proof of this somewhere?

Comment: I think I understand: one could theoretically enumerate every possible unfinished sudoku puzzle and the solution to it. After doing this, finding a solution to an "arbitrary" sudoku puzzle is trivial. But I still maintain that your answer is left vague and it would be helpful to see an explanation (to both myself and others)

Comment: I must have must have misread the question. If $n=9$ then it can be solved in constant time, simply by enumerating the possible solutions.

Comment: @TylerDurden, you are free to add a new answer with a explanation as verbose about this as you want, really (and to downvote mine because it does not help you, because you do not like it, or simply because you feel like it) I personally prefer it as it stands. And, more importantly, it is certainly not wrong.

Comment: -1 Please add the disclaimer *if P$\neq$NP*

Answer (score 10):

Rather than strict NP-completeness, what I think what you're trying to ask is whether there is a transition similar to the one between 3-SAT and 2-SAT where the problem goes from being NP-hard to easy and in P.  There is such a transition, but 9x9 Sudoku is on the wrong side of it.  Solving a Sudoku puzzle is equivalent to deciding whether there is a valid [graph vertex coloring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring) using $k$ colors, where $k = n^2$ in your $n^2 \times n^2$ Sudoku instance.  The graph coloring problem is known to be NP-complete for values of $k$ > 2, so 9x9 Sudoku is still hard.